# Best Way for Getting Value from a Clicked Checkbox, with JQuery

Tags: ajax, jquery, checkbox

All,

Is this the best way to get the value of a currently-checked/unchecked checkbox?

The number of checkboxes is arbitrary so I need a way to get the value of the checkbox that was checked or unchecked.

By looking at Firebug, I see that by using:

```
this.defaultValue
```

I can get the value of the currently-checked/unchecked checkbox but not sure if that's really the best way.

Here is the HTML and below is the Javascript click handler

```
    <div id="ClubSponsorshipPartial">
 <table class="table-grid">
  <tr>
      <td> 
           <input type="checkbox" value="000000244187" id="slpBackgroundCheck" name="slpBackgroundCheck"> Person #1
           <input type="checkbox" value="000000533796" id="slpBackgroundCheck" name="slpBackgroundCheck"> Person #2
           <input type="checkbox" value="000000533796" id="slpBackgroundCheck" name="slpBackgroundCheck"> Person #3
       </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
 </div>





     <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $("#ClubSponsorshipPartial input[type=checkbox]").click(function (e) {
    var queryStr = '';
    var clubKeyNumber = '';
    var receivedBackgroundCheckChecked = false;

    var memberId = this.defaultValue
    clubKeyNumber = 'K06253';
    receivedBackgroundCheckChecked = ($("#ClubSponsorshipPartial input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked") ? "true" : "false");
    queryStr = "memberId=" + memberId + "&isChecked=" + receivedBackgroundCheckChecked;
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Dashboard/BackgroundCheck',
            data: queryStr,
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
            $.notification({
                content: 'SLP Advisor Background Check status saved.',
                error: false,
                timeout: 5000
            });
            },
            failure: function (data) {
            $.notification({
                content: 'Error saving SLP Advisor Background Check status.',
                error: true,
                timeout: 5000
            });
            },
            timeout: 5000
        });
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: First. You have 3 "slpBackgroundCheck" whit this ID... set same name only

Comment: Second. You could change $("#slpBackgroundCheck") by $('[name=slpBackgroundCheck]') ... or set a class on each checkbox  and access using $('.yourChkClass') ...

Comment: Once you've taken care of the ID issue, replace `$("#slpBackgroundCheck")` with `$(this)` to make sure you're dealing with the checkbox that was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the id should be unique in your page document, and you should use `$(this)` to mapping current DOM, you can try below code, may help;

http://jsfiddle.net/kJQr9/